# Bug; looks like MathJax is eating up dollars signs in "Hot Network Questions"

Tags: bug, mathjax, hot-questions-list

Looks like MathJax is eating up dollars signs in related questions.

[image]

Comment: See also [this post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/269811/mathjax-rendering-in-hot-network-questions-sidebar)